# Connectivity in Directed Graph

Tags: union-find, depth-first-search, directed-graphs, breadth-first-search

Connectivity in undirected graph can be easily identified using Disjoint Union Set (Union Find). Is there any way to check connectivity in a directed graph efficiently other than doing Depth First search or Breadth First Search? Is there any data structure that solves this problem efficiently.

For Example :

```
a -> b -> c
e -> b -> c

hasPath(a, c) => true
hasPath(e, c) => true
hasPath(e, a) => false
hasPath(c, a) => false
```

Comment: How much preprocessing time is allowed? With $O(n^2)$ preprocessing you can answer queries in $O(1)$ time.

Comment: preprocessing is fine as long as the the memory does not exceed O(n). O(n) or O(n log n) time is preferred.

Comment: What is the problem with BFS\DFS?

Comment: @nirshahar Consider a graph with million nodes. For multiple queries each query consumes O(n) time which is costly.

Comment: You can still use BFS and DFS as part of a pre-proseccing step to generate the super-graph DAG, and map each original node to its corresponding super-node in the super-graph

Comment: @nirshahar Yes I thought of this but it would cost much more space. For a million Nodes it would take around 500 GB memory at worst case. So if there is no way to do this then i have to compromise of time only as i don't have that much space.

Comment: Any pre-processing you may hope to use will have to at least add one bit per graph node, so I doubt you can do anything without a lot of extra memory (most likely things will take way more than one bit...)

Comment: @VeeraKumar Could you please edit your question and mention your requirements as discussed in the comment section above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you stated is known as the Graph Reachability Query problem. You may want to check this paper: [An Efficient Algorithm for Answering Graph
Reachability Queries](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1071.8355&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and the references therein.

The paper discusses the previously known results as well as optimizes both on the space complexity and the query complexity. The algorithm takes $O(n^2 + bn \cdot \sqrt{b})$ pre-processing time and $O(bn)$ space, where $b$ is the width of the graph, defined as the size of the largest subset $U$ of $V$ such that for every pair of nodes $u, v \in U$, there does not exist a path from $u$ to $v$ or from $v$ to $u$. The query complexity of the algorithm is $O(\log b)$.

Note that the value of $b$ could actually be $\Theta(|V|)$, for example, take a star graph on $n$ vertices. Therefore, the algorithm might be more useful for dense graphs, for which $b$ is usually small.